# How do I fix stale postmaster.pid file on Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, macos

I went to view a postgres schema on my local (MacOS 11) database, and was not able to view my schemas.
Connection Refused in PGSQL Editor! (DBeaver specifically)

[image: connection refused DBeaver]

So I opened my Postgres desktop application, and got the warning message, "Stale postmaster.pid file"

How can I fix this?

(This example is Postgres 12, but i'm sure this fix will work on later versions)

[image: stale Postmaster.pid postgres 12 dashboard screenshot]

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The problem is that the postmaster.pid file needs to be removed manually and regenerated by postgres, and these are the steps to do it. Keep in mind the version might change, (var-12, might be var-13,14,15 etc), but the theory remains the same.

1. Open your terminal, and cd into the postgres directory: `cd /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres`
2. Make sure you're in the right place, `ls` you should see something like `var-12` or `var-<version #>`
3. Verify the file is there, `ls var-12` (`var-XX` is equivalent to your current PGSQL version)
4. Verify the Postgres server is not running by viewing desktop app

Version might change so could be var-12/13/14+, etc etc depending on age of this article.

```
Library/Application Support/Postgres
➜ ls var-12
PG_VERSION           pg_hba.conf          
pg_replslot          pg_subtrans
postgresql.auto.conf base
pg_ident.conf        pg_serial
pg_tblspc            postgresql.conf
global               pg_logical
pg_snapshots         pg_twophase
postgresql.log       pg_commit_ts
pg_multixact         pg_stat
pg_wal               postmaster.opts
pg_dynshmem          pg_notify
pg_stat_tmp          pg_xact
postmaster.pid  <---- (what you're looking for, verify it exists)
```

1. Then remove postmaster.pid, `rm var-12/postmaster.pid`
2. or `rm var-<PG version #>/postmaster.pid`
3. Go back to your console, start your postgres server, and it should be functioning again, and you should have full access to your schemas.

Comment: there is no pid file in var-12, and I still get the Stale postmaster.pid file

Comment: Do we know why this happens?? I've had it happen to me twice now.

Comment: Method is working for Postgres 14

Answer (score 21):

Since the question was using the desktop app, I thought I'd just add to the answers here with a version independent non-bash approach:

1. Open `Postgres` desktop app
2. Click `Server Settings...`
3. Click `Show` on the data directory

[image: Show data directory]

4. Rename or delete `postmaster.pid`

[image: Delete or rename postmaster.pid]

5. Click `Start` in the desktop app again.

[image: Start SQL server]

Comment: I am more CLI than GUI dude, but i appreciates this answer!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I used the code `rm var-13/postmaster.pid` and solved.

Comment: Where is it exactly? Like /users/<>/...?

Comment: `cd /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres`

Answer (score 4):

```
cd /Users/<UserName>/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/

ls
```

Then we may view any of the directory names, such as var-9, var-10, var-11, etc... depending on which PostgreSQL version we have installed.

Following that, if we can see var-11,

```
cd var-11
rm postmaster.pid
```